# insertion sorting algorithm brings the largest number to the bottom

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I´m working on insertion sorting a bunch of numbers but I just can´t wrap my head around it. I´m pretty sure the "j = i - 1"  is wrong and a bunch of other things, and I´d really appreciate it if you guys could point out my mistakes so I can fix them.

```
public class temp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numbrid[] = {2, 5, 9, 7, 1, 4, 3, 8, 6};
    System.out.println("before:");
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < numbrid.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(numbrid[i]);
    }
    //sorting
    System.out.println("after:");
    for (i = 1; i < numbrid.length; i++) {
        j = i - 1;
        while (numbrid[i] < numbrid[j]) {
            k = numbrid[i];
            numbrid[i] = numbrid[j];
            numbrid[j] = k; // swaps their places
        }
    }
    for ( i = 0; i < numbrid.length; i++ ) {
        System.out.println(numbrid[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: all this does is it takes the largest number and brings it to the bottom

Comment: Your implementation of the sort algorithm is wrong. Take a look at the pseudocode [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) - you should be able to convert it to Java with relative ease.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few problems in your `for` loop:

1. Insertion has to use just 1 input per iteration (of the outside `for`), hence you have to assign the value to your temp variable *before* you get into your `while`

   ```
   for (i = 1; i < numbrid.length; i++) {
     k = numbrid[i];
   ```
2. Step on to the while loop with replacing the next number with the previous one till you reach your temp number (till your `numbrid[j] > k`)

   ```
   while ((j > -1) && (numbrid[j] > k)) {
   numbrid[j + 1] = numbrid[j];
   j--;
   }
   ```
3. Assign your temp value to the next element in your array

   ```
   numbridj + 1] = k;
   ```
4. Move on with your for loop

Hence, your `for` loop becomes:

```
...
for (i = 1; i < numbrid.length; i++) {
    k = numbrid[i];
    j = i - 1;
    while ((j > -1) && (numbrid[j] > k)) {
        numbrid[j + 1] = numbrid[j];
        j--;
    }
    numbrid[j + 1] = k;
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two errors:

- You musn't swap `j` and `i` elements but `j` and `j+1`
- You are forgetting to decrease `j`

oooh @PopoFibo anticipated :( well I'll post anyway..